# How to store data in laravel when having loop for dynamic column names?

Tags: arrays, database, laravel, for-loop, dynamic

This is my Controller Code to store data in database

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $user = Auth::user();
    $input = $request->all();
    $mycheck= $input['mycheck'];
    //return $mycheck;
```

It returns

- {

  - "23": "1",
  - "24": "2",
  - "25": "1",
  - "26": "2",
  - "27": "1",
  - "28": "2",
  - "29": "1",
  - "30": "2",
  - "31": "1",
  - "32": "2"
- }

  ```
    //return $input;
    $user_response = new CovidUserResponses();
    $user_response->user_id = $user->id;
    $user_response->recorded_date_time = Carbon::now();
    $user_response->temperature = $request->input('temperature');
    foreach($mycheck as $index => $mc)
    {
        //return $index;
        $user_response->question_$mc[$index] = $mc;
       // $user_response->question_1 = 1;

    } 
    return $user_response;
  ```

  }

where as i need for this statement should pick question automatically with respect to its index and saves  the data in database. // $user_response->question_{{$index}} = 1;

My Table for CovidUserResponse is ---

```
Schema::create('covid_user_responses', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('question_1');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('question_2');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('question_3');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('question_4');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('question_5');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('question_6');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('question_7');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('question_8');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('question_9');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('question_10');
            $table->boolean('status');
            $table->decimal('temperature', 5, 1);
            $table->date('recorded_date_time');
            $table->timestamps();

            $table->foreign('user_id')
            ->references('id')
            ->on('users')
            ->onDelete('cascade');
        });
```

This is my form code to take input values --

```
<form action="{{ route('self-assessment.store') }}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" autocomplete="off">
                     @csrf
                            @foreach($covidquestions as $covidquestion) 
                                @if($covidquestion->question_type == "radio")
                                <div class="form-group row">
                                    <label class="col-12" for="name">{{ $covidquestion->question_no }} {{ $covidquestion->question_title }}</label>
                                    <div class="col-12">
                                        <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                                            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="mycheck[{{$covidquestion->id}}]" id="inlineRadio1" value="1">
                                            <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio1">Yes</label>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                                            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="mycheck[{{$covidquestion->id}}]" id="inlineRadio2" value="2">
                                            <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio2">No</label>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                @else
                                <div class="form-group row">
                                    <label class="col-12" for="temperature"> {{ $covidquestion->question_no }} {{ $covidquestion->question_title }}</label>
                                    <div class="col-12">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="temperature" name="temperature" placeholder="Enter Temperature.." required>
                                    </div>
                                </div> 
                                @endif
                            @endforeach
                                <div class="form-group row">
                                    <div class="col-12">
                                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>  
                                    </div>
                                </div>
</form>
```

Comment: I think there is an issue in your `blade` file.
Please check if `name=mycheck[{{$covidquestion->id}}]` is creating correct indexes.

Comment: so 32 is `question_32` ... there are more than 10?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were just not appending the correct value to the string:

```
foreach ($mycheck as $id => $value) {
    $user_response->setAttribute('question_'. $id, $value);
}
```